# MSXML 6 Service Pack Setup Interrupted

Tags: msxml-6

Trying to install KB954459, I get the "MSXML 6 Service Pack Setup Interrupted" message.

Tried to unistall MSXML 6 SP2 first, but nothing in Add/Remove programs applet, and Installer Cleanup Utility does not list any MSXML items on my system (XP SP3), although msxml6.dll has version 6.20.1076.0.

Any ideas?